# Avoid crashing build using Pull Request and CI

Tags: git, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions, pull-request

I'm trying to optimize the workflow for an Android project.

I ran into a problem were having two Pull request ready to merge:

- PR 1 Change the parameters for a function
- PR 2 Adds a new call to the same, original function without changing the function itself so no conflicts would be detected
- PR1 merge -> PR 2 merge -> Build will crash on main

Right now, we are forcing to sync branches before to merge but this is not sustainable.
Taking into account that we want to ensure 100% availability in the main branch.

How could I set up the workflow to avoid this?

So far, here are my alternatives:
1-  Run a check in the CI to trigger a build and revert the commits if it fails.
2- Run a static analysis tool to prevent this (I'm open for suggestions).

Comment: How this doesn't cause a conflict on GIT level ? That should be more like PR1 merge, PR2 won't merge as it has conflicts. You have to rebase PR2 on top of master after PR1 is merged.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Whether you'd get a conflict and/or compile-time error depends on the language, calling conventions, and more; in a lot of languages you'd find the first PR changes the function definition in file A and two calls in files A and B, and the second PR adds a third call in file C, so there's no conflict at all.